# Дочерние селекторы

Tags: html, css

Недавно начал изучать HTML + CSS и столкнулся с проблеммой, проходя моменты с дочерними селекторами. Есть простой код:

```
<div>
<p>Известно, что пустыня обладает неправильной формой, которую
принимаем прямоугольной. Это достигается одним из двух способов —
<i>включением частей</i>, выходящих за пределы области пустыни
или их <i>отбрасыванием</i></p>
</div>
<p>
<h1>Текст1<h2>Текст2</h2></h1>
</p>
```

Стили такие:

```
p > h1{
    color: red;
}

h1 > h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

Ни первый стиль, ни второй не работает вообще. Я не знаю почему так происходит.

Comment: Заголовки `h` не вкладываются один в другой. Также нет необходимости вкладывать их в параграфы `p`. Необходимо соблюдать иерархию тегов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically
>   close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>`
>   tag.

то есть

> Параграф (абзац) - это блоковый (перевод?) элемент, он автоматически
>   закрывается, если другой блоковый элемент начинается до того, как
>   встретился закрывающий `</p>` тэг.

Таким образом, в DOM-дереве страницы нет элементов `h1` внутри элементов `p`. То же самое - для элементов `h2` внутри элементов `h1`.

---

> Про тег `<p>` я понял, но не понял про `h1>h2`

`h1` и `h2` - это тоже блоковые элементы, один не может быть внутри другого. Даже если Вы напишете разметку html как в вопросе, браузер все равно создаст невложенные элементы `h1` и `h2`.

```html
<h1>Текст1<h2>Текст2</h2></h1>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про тег <p> я понял, но не понял про h1>h2

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый А теперь?

Comment: Да, но просто div тоже блочные, но ведь можно же писать <div><h1>Пример</h1><div></div></div>

Comment: И стиль div > div будет работать

Comment: @Igor плюсанул, Игорь

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый вкладывать div в div можно, вкладывать h1 в div тоже можно, а вкладывать h2 в h1 нельзя. Это определяется не блочностью, а семантикой тега

Comment: Это потому что вы используете фирменные слова)) А можно на пальцах: Браузер смотрит код... натыкается на <h1> - открыто, ок, идем дальше... Оппа, h1 еще не закрыт, а натыкается на <h2>. Браузер думает, что так не пойдет. Сначала автоматически закрывает </h1>, и потом уже идет дальше по <h2>. А элементы div допускают вложение друг в друга.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div>h1 {
  color: red;
}

div>h2 {
  color: blue;
}

div i {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Известно, что пустыня обладает неправильной формой, которую принимаем прямоугольной. Это достигается одним из двух способов —
    <i>включением частей</i>, выходящих за пределы области пустыни или их <i>отбрасыванием</i></p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Текст1</h1>
  <h2>Текст2</h2>
</div>
```

**Знак**  `>` ставить необязательно, достаточно пробела.

**Если** у тебя стоит цель из заголовков построить визуально предложение или что-то вроде этого, то:

```css
div.zagolovki, h1, h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
div.zagolovki h1 {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zagolovki"><h1>Текст1</h1><h2>Текст2</h2></div>
```

Comment: Про h1 я понял, их нельзя вкладывать потому что они блочные, но <div><h1>Пример</h1><div></div></div> ведь работает и он тоже блочный.

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый они автоматически переносятся в html-коде.

Comment: Не понял. Что значит автоматически переносятся?

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый вот твой код: <h1>Текст1<h2>Текст2</h2></h1>. Впиши его например в обычную html-страницу, и посмотри как в результате выводятся тэги. Да и визуально сразу будет заметно, что вначале h1 сверху, и h2 снизу. Чего тут непонятного? если ты хочешь текст внутри текста сделать, то сделай это при помощи div или span например. Какую ты цель себе ставишь?

Comment: Моя цель понять следующее: выше мне писали, что при записи <h1><h2></h2></h1> не выйдет применить подобный стиль h1>h2 потому что они блочные, но если писать <div><div></div></div> то можно сделать div > div{color: red;} и все будет работать. Почему во втором случае все работает? Ведь div блочный как и h1. Он исключение?

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый ведь сказал в html автоматом сносит... Потому что это разные тэги. h1-h6 всегда будут с новой строки. div - нет. У них разные предназначения.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev, ненужно вводить людей в заблуждение. Знак `>` даёт понять что использовать нужно только дочерние элементы первого уровня, а без него  все дочерние. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/3bz6ftwg/)

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый, написали же: абзацы и заголовки блочные по принципу, но особенные, так сказать, по должности. При попадании внутрь них другого блочного элемента они автоматически закрываются перед ним. Как гласит история их внедрения в первый html - "так будет, ибо нехер".